# Help with proof: limit g(x)/f(x)=0 as $x \rightarrow x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Given: lim x$\rightarrow x_0$ f(x) = $\infty$ and lim x$\rightarrow x_0$ g(x) = L>0.

Prove that lim x$\rightarrow x_0$ $(g(x)/f(x))$ = 0.

My attempt:

Suppose that lim f(x)=$\infty$ and lim g(x) = L > 0.

Since lim f(x) = $\infty$, we know that if $\forall$A, $\exists \delta_1$>0, if 0<$|x-x_0|$<$\delta_1$, then $f(x)>A.$

So, $1/f(x)$$\leq$$1/A$ holds as long as $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Further, lim$g(x)$=L>0, if $\forall$A, $\exists \delta_2$>0, if 0<$|x-x_0|$<$\delta_2$, then $|g(x)-L|$<$\epsilon$

So, we have $L-\epsilon<g(x)<L+\epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon = \epsilon_2A-L$, then we get that $g(x)<L+\epsilon_2A-L=\epsilon A$.

Using Limit Properties, we finally have: $lim g(x)/lim f(x) < (\epsilon_2A)/A$=$\epsilon$

QED

I was hoping to get some input on my proof. I know it needs more work, but I'm not sure where and how to improve it at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make things easier, since $g(x)\to L$ when $x\to x_0$, there is $\delta >0$ and $M>0$ s.t. $|g(x)|\leq M$ for all $|x-x_0|<\delta $. Therefore, $$\left|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|\leq \frac{|M|}{|f(x)|},\quad \text{if }|x-x_0|<\delta.$$

If $\varepsilon >0$, take $\tilde \delta \in (0,\delta )$ s.t. $|f(x)|>\frac{M}{\varepsilon }$, and you get $$\left|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|<\varepsilon ,$$
whenever $|x-x_0|<\tilde \delta $. The claim follows.

Comment: @user2661923: it was a Typo. I edited it.

Comment: With your correction, your approach is now valid.  My only criticism is that if it were me, I would explicitly demonstrate your assertion around $M$, namely that if you specify $\epsilon_1 = L/2$, then there exists a $\delta_1$ such that for all $x$ in $(x_0 - \delta_1, x_0 + \delta_1)$, you have that $0 < L/2 = [L - L/2] < g(x) < [L + L/2] = 3L/2 = M.$  So, you have that for any $x$ within $\delta_1$ of $x_0$, 0 < g(x) < M.

Comment: Or You could procede as follows: For $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\delta_1>0$ such that $g(x)<L+\varepsilon$ for all $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ and for $A=\frac{L+\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ there is a $\delta_2>0$ such that $f(x)>A$ for $|x-x_0|<\delta_2$ and thus for $\delta=\min \{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ it holds that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}|<\frac{L+\varepsilon}{A}=\varepsilon$.

Comment: @PeterMelech Interesting and valid sidestep of the issue of whether $g(x)$ is negative.  True that regardless of whether $g(x)$ negative, the fact that $L > 0$ implies that $|g(x)| < L + \epsilon.$

Comment: Was my proof completely incorrect?